# How to know what version of C++ compiler is installed on Linux server?

Tags: linux, c++, redhat-enterprise-linux

We have a RHEL5.5 server, and the system engineering guys at my company said that they have recently installed Intel C++ 11.1 compiler on the box.

But, when I do a cc -v, I get

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --enable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
```

I did a which cc, and it points to /usr/bin where cc is a soft link to gcc. People at the system engineering aren't too clear about the path where they have installed it either.

There is nothing that says if this is the Intel compiler or the default gcc compiler.

So, is there a command that lists the compiler name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Intel C++ compiler is usually installed in `/opt/intel`. There's a script you have to run to set up your environment to use it, usually `iccvars.sh`.

For the most common installation options, this should work:

```
. /opt/intel/bin/iccvars.sh intel64
icc -v
```

Comment: maybe a silly question but does 64 indicate 64 bit? can I use intel32?

Comment: I used the option ia32

Comment: Yes, on a 64-bit installation, you can specify either 32-bit or 64-bit targets.

Answer (score 4):

> **There is nothing that says if this is the Intel compiler or the default gcc compiler.**

You quoted

> gcc version 4.1.2

Which suggests to me it is gcc not Intel

> **aren't too clear about the path where they have installed it**

Try `locate cc`